# Publish JMS messages using TLS authentication in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, activemq-artemis, jks

Could not make secure connection to my secured application (message-broker) using JMeter

Hi

I got 3 files for performance testing a secured application - client.pem, client-key.pem and ca.pem files

I tried to convert pem files to p12 file by executing the below command using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.pem -inkey client-key.pem -CAfile ca.pem -out client.p12
```

And then edited the system.properties file to mention the keystore type, path & password. Restarted my JMeter and ran JMS Publisher. But still I am getting "Failed to create session factory" error in JMeter.

Also, tried with jks file as well. While importing the jks file in Jmeter using SSL Manager option, it is not prompting for password. I could not see any keystore relevant related log entries in JMeter log file. When I try to execute the JMS publisher, I am getting the same "Failed to create session factory" error.

Can someone help me to understand what went wrong in my steps and also how to make a secure connection to my message-broker? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: How is the `acceptor` on the broker configured?

Comment: What URL are you using on the client?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack-trace for the error you are seeing?

Comment: I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0 and the URL is tcp://brokerUrl<127.0.0.1>:61618 encrypted one, will check acceptor configuration

Comment: Created truststore.jks file using ca file. After adding that into systems.properties file in JMeter, I am getting username null (JMSExecpetion:Unable to validate user from /<ipaddress>, Username:null, SSLcertifcate subject DN:unavailable) error when I run it.. Hope it makes successful connection but how to pass proper credentials now?

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure to use `ssl` instead of `tcp` protocol in the connection URL
2. You might need to amend the connection factory to [ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.html)
3. You might need to provide not only the keystore but the [truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference) as well

In case anything goes wrong [enable debug logging for JMeter's JMS components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and see what does [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file say.

More information: [ActiveMQ - How do I use SSL](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl)

Comment: Thanks much for your quick response. Can you please help me with more details? If I change the connection URL, JMeter says it's wrong URL. What is the relevant jar file for ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory? I tried to use activemq-client jar but still getting namenotfoundexception in JMeter. For the truststore, should I get it from Developer and add it to .p12 file? If yes, how should I add? If no, how to generate the truststore and add it to JMeter? Please assist

Comment: Although ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire client, using `ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory` and [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl) is not ideal because that stuff is really for ActiveMQ "Classic". Ideally applications would be using the core JMS client which uses the `tcp` schema with the `sslEnabled=true` URL parameter. See more [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-ssl).